# Getting text from an enclosure tag with XPath

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I just started learning XPath, lxml, and python this week.  I would like to know if there is an XPath expression that will get the url text out of an enclosure tag.  Is this possible?

The XML I'm dealing with:

```
<enclosure  url="http://nakeddiscovery.com/libsyn/Naked_Scientists_Show_17.08.14.mp3"  length="51671039"  type="audio/mpeg" ></enclosure>
```

I can get a list with this statement :

```
urls = parsedFeed.xpath('//enclosure/@url')
```

then loop through the list, but I was hoping for a more direct way.  I've tried  `//enclosure/@url/text()`, `//enclosure/@url.text`, etc...   And many variations of that.  I have Googled it, searched stackoverflow, but nada.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using index :

```
parsedFeed.xpath('//enclosure/@url')[0]
```

Comment: Thanks!  That was just what I needed.  I swear I tried that before, but I guess I put the brackets in the wrong place.